# expandable-spinner : How to implement expandable spinner entry in Android

Tags: android, android-spinner

I am building an Android application, in which i've a spinner item. The spinner entry is a category, and there are sub category in each category.

I want to implement a UI, such that, when i click a spinner entry, i must get another spinner, showing the sub-categories for that category. (Something like how 
Windows Program menu works).

Here's and image of what it must look like -

[image]

Consider the drop down as a spinner.

I figured out these many ways -

1. Implementing Spinner of Spinners.
2. Populating new spinner on every item-selected.

I am confused, as which method is efficient and easy to maintain.

Please help me get a solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I dont know why people try to incorporate desktop / web based design into a movel environment wich is a different design concept.

Comment: Hi Gilson, previously i didn't knew the name of such UI design. Hence i tried to show via an example image. However, I was going through Android Design pattern articles on developer.android.com, I found that Android Multi-plane layout suits my need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look at this answer and extend that to multiple ListPopupWindows in some way.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16858218/1083313