# Activity theme not showing correctly

Tags: android, android-theme

Hello I am beginning Android and i am having this problem. When I run my application on API 23 this cardview is showing like this [image: API 23]

It should be showing like this [image: The same application on API 24]

I am having the same problem on Android 5.0

here is the code of the cardview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="4dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">



        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="@style/textsearch"
            android:text="filtro"
            android:id="@+id/filtro"

            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/boton_cerrar"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_close_box"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@null"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>


        <Spinner android:text="@string/opcion"
            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:minHeight="50dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/filtro"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/texto"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"

            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/spinner"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/spinner"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/spinner"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"

            />

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**theme-values.xml ---------------------------------------**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <color name="theme_primary">#3F51B5</color>
    <color name="theme_primary_dark">#303F9F</color>
    <color name="theme_primary_medium">#7986CB</color>
    <color name="theme_accent">#FFC107</color>
    <color name="theme_secondary">#795548</color>
    <color name="theme_secondary_dark">#5D4037</color>

    <color name="colorPrimary">@color/theme_primary</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/theme_primary_dark</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">@color/theme_accent</color>

    <!-- Drawer Properties -->
    <dimen name="drawerAvatarWidthHeight">80dp</dimen>

    <!-- Dimensions -->
    <dimen name="statusBarHeight">0dp</dimen>

    <!-- Booleans -->
</resources>
```

**theme-values.xml (v19)  ---------------------------------------**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <color name="theme_primary">#3F51B5</color>
    <color name="theme_primary_dark">#303F9F</color>
    <color name="theme_primary_medium">#7986CB</color>
    <color name="theme_accent">#FFC107</color>
    <color name="theme_secondary">#795548</color>
    <color name="theme_secondary_dark">#5D4037</color>

    <color name="colorPrimary">@color/theme_primary</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/theme_primary_dark</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">@color/theme_accent</color>

    <!-- Drawer Properties -->
    <dimen name="drawerAvatarWidthHeight">80dp</dimen>

    <!-- Dimensions -->
    <dimen name="statusBarHeight">0dp</dimen>

    <!-- Booleans -->
</resources>
```

**theme-values.xml (v21)  ---------------------------------------**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <!-- Drawer Properties -->
    <dimen name="statusBarHeight">24dp</dimen>
    <!-- Booleans -->
</resources>
```

**styles.xml**

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
 <style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>

<style name="AppBar.Dark" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"></style>


<!-- FIXME: Replace toolbar with appbar.. -->
<style name="ToolBarTheme" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/ic_action_navigation_menu</item>
    <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/ic_action_navigation_menu</item>
</style>

<style name="ViewSeparator">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">1dp</item>
    <item name="android:background">#cccccc</item>
</style>

<style name="cardview_text">
    <item name="android:typeface">normal</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/color_cardview_text</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20dp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>

<style name="cardview_header">
    <item name="android:typeface">normal</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">25dp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>

<style name="textsearch">
    <item name="android:typeface">normal</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20dp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>
```

**styles.xml (v19)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**styles.xml (v21)**

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

   <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
        <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>

    </style>

</resources>
```

Comment: Post your styles.xml for all the versions you have defined

Comment: I think problem occurs in Styles

Answer (score 1):

change background color of cardview:

```
card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
```

Comment: works fine but the spinner of the cardview and the spinner above is not showing the text. Is there any property to fix that?

Comment: Accept as correct if it was helpful.

check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9476665/how-to-change-spinner-text-size-and-text-color

you can set customized textView in spinner.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the layout to Linear layout and also checkout this URL.. it looks similar to this..

[How do you anchor a Dropdown spinner to a parent Linearlayout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16710159/how-do-you-anchor-a-dropdown-spinner-to-a-parent-linearlayout)

Comment: Can you add more details to your answer please?